# Show that if $X$ is path-connected, then every path $\alpha :I \to X$ are homotopic with each other (neglecting the condition rel $\{0,1\})$.

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

> Show that if $X$ is path-connected, then every path $\alpha :I \to X$ are homotopic with each other (neglecting the condition rel $\{0,1\})$.

Since $X$ is path-connected we have that for every $a,b \in X$ there exists $\beta :I \to X$ such that $\beta(0)=a$ and $\beta(1)=b$.

Now for paths $\alpha, \gamma : I \to X$ what I need to find is a continuous map $h:I^2 \to X$ such that $$h(x,0)=\alpha(x) \text{ and } h(x,1)=\gamma(x).$$

How is the path-connectedness condition helpful here? I don't see how I can use it. I suppose I somehow need to take into account the fact that I can join every two points with paths when considering the homotopy, but I cannot figure out how.

Comment: Hint: first show that if $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are constant paths, they are homotopic to each other.

Comment: If $\alpha_1, \alpha_2 : I \to X$ are constant with values say $\alpha_1(s) = x_1$ and $\alpha_2(s) = x_2$ for all $s \in I$, then they're essentially just points. Now picking $\beta : I \to X$ such that $\beta(0) = x_1$ and $\beta(1) = x_2$ I can construct $h : I^2 \to X$ such that $h(s,t)=\beta(t)$?

Comment: Looks good. Now prove that every path is path homotopic to aconstant path.

Comment: What is the intuition here? I don't know where the constant paths came into consideration in the first place. @LeeMosher

Comment: The intuition is that since the endpoints are not fixed, you can shrink any path to its starting point, and since the space is path connected, you can move that point to any other point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem you want to take advantage of a very important fact about homotopy, namely it is an equivalence relation.

Knowing that, suppose you can also prove the following two things:

1. Every path is homotopic to a constant path (which is done already in another link on this site).
2. Any two constant paths are homotopic to each other, assuming path connectivity (which you did in the comments).

So, let $f, g : [0,1] \to X$ be any two paths in a path connected space $X$.

You know from item 1 that there exists a constant path $P : [0,1] \to X$ such that

3. $f$ is homotopic to $P$.

You also know from item 1 that $g$ is homotopic to some constant path that I'll denote $Q : [0,1] \to X$. Applying the symmetry law, it follows that

4. $Q$ is homotopic to $g$.

You also know from item 2 that

5. $P$ is homotopic to $Q$.

Since $f$ is homotopic to $P$, and $P$ is homotopic to $Q$, and $Q$ is homotopic to $g$, you may conclude from the transitive law that $f$ is homotopic to $g$.